# How to wrap text in first div but use the available space where the second div's width should be adjusted to the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have two divs on the same line. The first (left) div shall use all available space and wrap the text if the text is too long for the div's width. The second div's width (aligned right) should be adjusted to its content. The width of the first div must not set to percentage or fixed pixels. The second div's content vary.

I have created a sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/2n6n5oLe/

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="message">
    This is a very long text and should not overlap the buttons, but should wrap. This is a very long text and should not overlap the buttons, but should wrap. This is a very long text and should not overlap the buttons, but should wrap.
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" text="Button1" />
    <input type="button" text="Button2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.message {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: lime;
  text-align: right;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is if the text gets too long it overlaps the second div.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should look into flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Your problem it's `position: absolute;` in `.message`. Absolute takes elements out of the flow and doesn't takes space (use your developer tools to inspect it and you will see `buttons` is under `message`). Take a look at the answers, there are some solutions there, depending on the specifics of what you need you could solve it with flexbox, inline-block, float, position absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox.

https://jsfiddle.net/2n6n5oLe/5/

Using your HTML, all you need is:

```
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.message {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

Comment: Looks almost good, but how can I achieve that the buttons are aligned right if the text is short?

Comment: `text-align: right` does it. Here's that and also using `flex-grow` on the `.message` DIV to make it take up all the space if the message is short (I think that's what you were after, yes?)  https://jsfiddle.net/2n6n5oLe/11/

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `flex-box`

```css
.message {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: lime;
  text-align: right;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="message">
This is a very long text and should not overlap the buttons, but should wrap. This is a very long text and should not overlap the buttons, but should wrap. This is a very long text and should not overlap the buttons, but should wrap.
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<input type="button" value="Button1" />
<input type="button" value="Button2" />
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2n6n5oLe/3/)

Comment: If the text is short, the buttons are not aligned at the right end of the window.

Comment: Unfortunately not, if the text is changed to one character, the buttons are positioned directly after the text end and not at the right end of the window.